# How can we explain the 3-polarizing-filters experiment inside the Everett interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons

first of all I'm french, please be indulgent with my speaking. :)

I was trying to understand the 3-polarizing-filters experiment where more light passes through three filters (oriented at 0°, 22.5° and 45°) than two filters (0° and 45°). I chose these angles on purpose to comprehend the non-hidden-variable argument in the experiment.

Mathematically, I understand this experiment, but I like to think of quantum physics with Everett interpretation of parallel universes. I was wondering how we could explain these results (and then non-hidden-variable argument) in this interpretation. Furthermore, what becomes the hidden variables in Everett interpretation, does it even have a sense as each possibility coexists with others?

Finally, there is this variation of the experiment where the filters aren't aligned in space but separated by long distances (more distance that light can travel in the time of the experiment). By repeating the experiment with combinations of two filters, one photon at a time, we find out the same proportions and probabilities. Is this also explainable in Everett interpretation?

Thank you for your answers. :)

Comment: There are no hidden variables here. When (un)polarized light is incident on a polarizers, the light that comes through is polarized. The incoming light is unaffected. The outgoing light is polarized in the orientation of the polarizing filter because the fraction of light that isn't polarized with the filter gets absorbed.

Comment: And the idea of the filters being too far apart for light to travel is nonsense. If the light doesn't have enough time to travel between the filters, the light doesn't hit the filters in the first place. There is no experiment.

Comment: OK, I just saw the Minute Physics video you are almost certainly referencing. Keep in mind that light polarization filters were used as an analogy for a real quantum mechanical effect. The analogy works because the underlying math is the same. You can even argue that there is a real quantum test being done, but I don't agree that a macroscopic property of EM fields can be called quantum.